# How to reconfigure my Xbox 360 hard drive back into a hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

I first had a 20G hard drive on my Xbox and I was running low on space. I got a 60G hard drive and a cheap transfer cable off Amazon. I accidentally plugged it in the wrong way and configured it so that the only way to use the hard drive is if you have it plugged in like if you are transfering data. You can't put it on the top because it says that there is no hard drive plugged in. Also, out of the 60G, I was only allowed to use 32G. Now I'm running low on space again and wondering if there is any way to configure it back into a hard drive where you can place it on the top and not need a cable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the drive while it is plugged in to the top of the xbox.

WARNING:Formatting will wipe your drive. If you can, move your save games (very small files) to the cloud and your usb drive. Finally, Format the drive and if you can't reclaim close to 60 GB, (54 GB is average) then find out how to open the drive to make sure that someone didn't sell you a 40GB drive.